# How to prevent custom control from being excluded in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, linker, xamarin.ios, custom-controls

In my Xamarin.iOS app I have a library with custom controls. It is can be added to the storyboard but when I run the app control is not displayed and I get this error `Unknown class [ControlName] in Interface Builder file.`
But if I add code `var type = typeof([ClassName]);` in my `AppDelegate` everything is fine - no errors and control is displayed.
I understand that control is removed by linker but how can I preserve the control without adding additional build parameters?

Comment: What about other controls in the same library? It looks like linker doesn't see any references do that library and removes it completely. One of Xamarin suggestion was in such case to create a dummy empty Init function in library and call it in your platform specific code to load library

Comment: @YuriS yeah, I know about those options. But I want to have my custom controls in separate project and is looking for some less dodgy way to solve the issue.

Comment: Then may be something from here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/